# Concat and make a string into a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, string-concatenation, nvarchar

I have a table where the month and year are separate, and I want to put them together and make the backend format to date. I tried cast/converting but I get an error of "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

This is the data

```
Accountingperiod | Accounting year
1                    2023
2                    2024
3                    2023
10                   2024
```

desired out put or any date output as long as its date

```
01/01/2023
02/01/2024
03/01/2023
10/01/2024
```

and when I output I try to cast the result but I get an error because of the string . Here is my code

```
select cast(concat(tb.AccountingPeriod,tb.AccountingYear) as date) as month_year_date  
from  ttbl_a  tb
```

Comment: Please avoid [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, and please show what results you are expecting for the sample data.

Comment: Guessing you need `select Convert(Date, DateTimeFromParts(AccountingYear,AccountingPeriod,1,0,0,0,0))`

Comment: or SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (AccountingYear,AccountingPeriod,1) from  ttbl_a  tb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @siggemannen, I used the below and it gave me what I want.

```
select DATEFROMPARTS (AccountingYear,AccountingPeriod,1) as yy_mm_date from ttbl_a

output

yy_mm_date
2023 -01-01  
2024 -02-01 
2023 -03-01 
2024 -10-01
```